# Not able to read Object values in Freemarker Template

Tags: scala, velocity, freemarker

I am naot able to read the scala/java object values in Freemarker Templet

I tried with this:

```
    case class ScheduleEmail(workOrderNo:String,
                             name:String,
                             woType:String,
                             numberOfAssets:String,
                              artisan:String,
                             dueDate:Date,priority:String)

    object ScheduleMailSending extends  App{
      val scheduleEmail1= List(ScheduleEmail("1", "Oil Change1", "WO", "3", "XYZ", Date.valueOf("2015-01-01"), "High"))
      val configaration = new Configuration
      configaration.setClassForTemplateLoading(this.getClass, "/")
      configaration.setObjectWrapper(new DefaultObjectWrapper())
      val data: util.HashMap[String, Object] = new util.HashMap[String, Object]
      val templet = configaration.getTemplate("schedule.ftl")
      data.put("mails",scheduleEmail1.asJava)
      val writer =new StringWriter()
     templet.process(data,writer)
      println("writer"+writer)
    }
```

and my template is-

```
<#list mails as std>

    WorkOrderNo:${std.workOrderNo}
    woType:${std.woType}

</#l
```

i am strugling with this ERROR-

```
SEVERE: Error executing FreeMarker template
FreeMarker template error:
For "${...}" content: Expected a string or something automatically convertible to string (number, date or boolean), but this evaluated to a sequence+method (wrapper: f.e.b.SimpleMethodModel):
==> std.workOrderNo  [in template "schedule.ftl" at line 2, column 15]

The failing instruction (FTL stack trace):
----------
==> ${std.workOrderNo}  [in template "schedule.ftl" at line 2, column 13]
----------

Java stack trace (for programmers):
```

Can anybody help me with this problem

Comment: Can we do similar templating in twirl engine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scala doesn't generate a getter method for `workOrderNo` (nor `BeanInfo`), so it's not a JavaBean property. It generates a `String workOrderNo()` method though (my Scala is rusty, but the error message also suggests that). So in the template you had to write `std.workOrderNo()`. Or, you should customize the `ObjectWrapper` to recognize `String workOrderNo()` as a property, via `setMethodAppearanceFineTuner(MethodAppearanceFineTuner)`. If you will work with Scala much, certainly that's what you should do.

Comment: In Freemarker 2.3.31 with scala even after customizing, ObjectWrapper its not working

Code:  val owb = new DefaultObjectWrapperBuilder(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_31)
  owb.setMethodAppearanceFineTuner(new MethodAppearanceFineTuner() {
    override def process(in: BeansWrapper.MethodAppearanceDecisionInput, out: BeansWrapper.MethodAppearanceDecision): Unit = {
      out.setReplaceExistingProperty(false);
      out.setMethodShadowsProperty(false)
    }
  })
  freemarkerConfig.setObjectWrapper(owb.build)

Comment: @PravinPundge You need to use `MethodAppearanceDecision.setExposeAsProperty(PropertyDescriptor)` there. See also the Javadoc of `freemarker.ext.beans.MethodAppearanceFineTuner.process`.