# Scala Dropwizard with Freemarker Views

Tags: scala, freemarker, dropwizard

Running latest Dropwizard (1.0.0) + the Scala (2.10.6) plugin.

Currently stumbling over properly rendering a Freemarker view.

My View:

`case class SimpleStringView(str:String) extends View("/templates/simpleString.ftl")`

Template:

`<p>param 'str' has value ${str}</p>`

Resource:

```
@GET
@Path("/echo/{echo}")
 def echo(@PathParam("echo") echo:String) : SimpleStringView = new SimpleStringView(echo)
```

produces the following error:

" freemarker.core.NonStringException: For "${...}" content: Expected a string or something automatically convertible to string (number, date or boolean), but this has evaluated to a method+sequence (wrapper: f.e.b.SimpleMethodModel):"

Changing "String" to "java.lang.String' in case class does not change the error message.

This does not look like a new problem and is most likely not Dropwizard but Freemarker + Scala related. Question however is: Has someone found a proper way around it ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Found that answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201528/not-able-to-read-object-values-in-freemarker-template

Comment: Pls. check this post (http://maus.sg/index.php/2016/08/29/dropwizard-with-scala-and-freemarker/) in order to overcome this challenge (its actually not a bug).